# InstallShield 2014 Run a custom action based on whether or not a dependency is installed

Tags: installshield

One of my company's products requires QuickTime. Our installer (made with InstallShield) at the moment attempts to install QuickTime automatically. Unfortunately, if a newer version of QuickTime is installed than the one we package, there is an error saying as much. Normally, this would be a minor inconvenience for our users, but if they run a silent install under these circumstances, the installer simply fails.

I could just update the version of QuickTime we package making it more likely that people do not run into this issue (which we will likely do anyway), but that is still a temporary workaround to the real issue. What really needs to happen is that the installer should check if QuickTime is already installed, and if it is, skip attempting to install QuickTime altogether.

I have looked into “Prerequisites” and “Custom Actions” but I have yet to find anything that would let me accomplish this. Am I looking in the right place? If so, what am I missing? If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

---

In my attempt to use a Prerequisite, I looked for a Registry Key that seemed sensible to use but it seems that QuickTime does not use a Registry Key to simply declare its current version (at least none that I could find). So, despite the fact that it's not remotely ideal, I tried to run the prerequisite depending on whether or not the file `QuickTimePlayer.exe` existed in `[ProgramFiles]QuickTime\`. I did not receive any error output, but on a test machine that had no QuickTime installed, the prerequisite did not run.

Answer (score 0):

How do you choose whether to try to install QuickTime?

Prerequisites are designed to detect if something is present, and, if not, install it. Prerequisites detect the presence of something through their conditions, typically looking for a known registry key or file with version information, and comparing against the version they would install. If it's missing or lower, install it; if it's equal or higher, skip it. But you must use the prerequisite editor to tell the prerequisite what to look for.

Comment: I did use the Prerequisite Editor (see the added description in my OP), but it silently failed.